# Performance of Pipes vs TCP/IP for a lot of requests with small data

Tags: tcp, serial-port, named-pipes, uart

We have a system with two micro-controllers and we are developing a simulation environment. In the real system the micro-controllers communicate trough UARTs sending small data back and forth all the time every millisecond (asking for variable values, sending commands, etc.).

In the simulation each micro-controller is a different application and we must find a way to communicate them. I have tried TCP/IP before but I notice from time to time there are very long time delays - for example it works ok and after 20 messages there is a second delay. I assume this is because TCP/IP is not designed to send small packets of ~10 bytes of data every millisecond. I have found some information about the issue but nothing conclusive on how to avoid the problem.

I was wondering if NamedPipes will work better. Will there be a huge performance hit when using NamedPipes to communicate back and forth ~10 bytes of data every ms? Should we look into another alternative? In the past the company has used virtual serial ports but that requires special third-party software and is too cumbersome to set up.

Comment: Modbus over TCP could be something you might want to look into. I don't know if you are on Linux but if you want to simulate UARTS, virtual serial ports look like the best choice, and there is no need for any third-party or commercial software, you have them at the kernel level. Even if you are on Windows you could use com0com, which is probably what you would call third party but there is not much set up to do... Not knowing how your simulator works it's very difficult to say much more than that, is it running two separate processes one for each microcontroller?

Comment: @MarcosG. I'm on Windows. I prefer not to have to setup some additional software, the less the better. Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory is a better approach.

Comment: looks legit, but it all depends on how much you want your communication to resemble a real UART. You could also code your own virtual serial ports, the [Windows driver samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/serial/VirtualSerial) repo has a couple of examples.